# Zip code/Postal Code and location Database

Tags: database, geolocation, location, zipcode

Can you please suggest me a good provider for "City, State, Country, Zip code/postal code and geocode" Database. We have a requirement in our project for location search autocomplete. So, we need a database with complete locations list for US and Canada on priority and other countries in future.

Please suggest a location database provider with above mentioned fields, which has accurate data.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/3166697) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

For Canada and the US see: https://geocoder.ca/?register=1&capostal=1
(
The Canadian Postal Code Dataset, last updated on 2018-07-01 00:15:15, with 5371 new records, has a total of 995676 unique postal codes.)

For your task you will most likely need: 2. Complete File - Canada Postal Address Database (20363095 records as of 2018-06-26 16:28:27)

As for the USA, fro the same source: the US Zip+4 Database Containing over 30Million Records

Answer (score -2):

For USA you can populate data from the link below :

http://gomashup.com/cms/usa_zipcode_json